# Replacing MVC's built in User objects with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project where I have NO local user management.  I have intergratred Facebook Connect successfully.  While this works, it makes my Controllers and Views messy and verbose.

I'd like to replace the default objects such as the User object exposed by Controllers and Views to return my FacebookUser object instead.

Anyone have a better solution than having my Controllers digging around in FacebookWebContex.? It just feels dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure which facebook library you are using.  But if you impliment IPrincipal and IIdentity in your FacebookUser object, you will be able to set HttpContext.Current.User to that FacebookUser which will allow you to pull that FacebookUser instance from the User property in the controller.

Comment: Where/when in the request life cycle should one set this object?  If I can do this before the view or controller access that property that would be an ideal solution.